# win10 black screen with cursor, presumably after an update, found solutions dont work

Tags: windows, windows-10, nvidia-geforce, black-screen-of-death

My windows 10 PC is trying something new which I don't like: It shows a black screen, with only my cursor. The solutions I've found don't work:

- I've tried WIN+P to open the multiple screen setting and changed it. It went from outputting to two screen to just one (the other no-signalled)
- I've tried CTRL+ALT+DEL and CTRL+SHIFT+ESC, both yield no result
- I'm trying to safeboot, but that's difficult as I don't know the keys, and my screen is black, and internet provides solutions for when you're already in windows.
- I've left it open for quite some time, in case it was doing something, no change
- I've tried a different output, and my other videocard (SLI setup)
- Motherboard doesnt have a video connector, so cant try that
- Took out both videocards, placed one back, no result. That card in other slot, no result. Tried the same with the other, all testcases result in the same result as the main problem
- Opened the case, got the dust out, but it wasnt much

It shows my BIOS screen properly, then the plain win10 logo with a loader, then just the loader, then nothing. After a while my mouse disappears, about the same time as my screensaver should start.

I've had windows 10 for some time now (in the free-update period, had WIN7), working fine.
I can hear the windows-is-loading tune when you normally go to the desktop after I press enter (I have no password). Also, when I (dis)connect some USB, it makes the sound windows is suposed to make.
Yes, I've rebooted, several times now.

I'm thinking towards a windows update gone wrong (but can't find similar cases), or NVIDIA driver update gone bad. Last time I shut down I pressed "Update and shutdown".

Does anyone have any suggestions or heared similar cases?

A bit of specs: It's a MSI motherboard, a normal HDD drive, two NVIDIA GeForce 550's. I've connected it to my Philips smartTV via HDMI and to a monitor via VGA. I don't know more specifics at this point, the whole setup is about 3, maybe 4 years old.

Comment: At what exact point does it show the black screen? Are you getting to the login screen before it happens?

Comment: Hi, I've added it to my question

Comment: You don't mention the specifics of the computer, but you have a video signal from the motherboard: a dsub or hdmi etc on the mainboard for use with CPU-based video? If so, can you physically remove the nvidia card and see if windows redetects. this will put you on a non-nvidia driver set.

Comment: Hi, the problem with that is dat my motherboard doesnt have a video signal, so I can't try that either (wanted to do so, I've checked).